# Extract data från each level of a factor in a function

Tags: r

I want to extract data for each level of a factor in a function, but how do I accomplish this in a function?

```
 id <- rep(1:5, each=3)
    trt <- rep(LETTERS[1:3],5)
    set.seed(1)
    q1 <- runif(15)
    set.seed(2)
    q2 <- runif(15)
    set.seed(3)
    q3 <- runif(15)
    df <- data.frame(id,trt,q1,q2,q3)
 

       
    func <- function(i){
    df <- df[df$trt==i,]
    for (n in 3:5) barplot(df[,n], main=colnames(df)[i])
    }
    func(A)
    func(B)
    func(C)
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to reinvent `subset` or `dplyr::filter`. In base R you could do `subset(df, trt == "A")`, or if you want your function to only work on `df` which is declared outside the function (which is a terrible idea) you could have `func <- function(i) { subset(df, trt == i) }` which you would use like `func("A")`

Comment: @AllanCameron Cameron Thanks for your response! I have added some details in the code. Why I want to make a function of it because I want to run more code on the data, here I have inserted a barplot. Then Im not sure how to make this function work...

Comment: You know it works as long as you put `A` or `B` or `C` in "quotes", don't you? Like `func("A")` returns a bar plot. Remember, none of these are variables - they are strings you are trying to match. It is possible to get it to work this way, but I would advise against it.